# How to use NSUserDefaults to save and return data

Tags: nsuserdefaults

```
func gameDidBegin(tetro: Tetro) {
    levelLabel.text = "\(tetro.level)"
    scoreLabel.text = "\(tetro.score)"

    //hiscoreLabel.text = "\(tetro.score)"

    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var score: Int = 0 `enter code here`{
        didSet {
            hiscoreLabel = (self.scoreLabel.text = "\(tetro.score)")
        }
    }

    scene.tickLengthMillis = TickLengthLevelOne

    // The following is false when restarting a new game
    if tetro.nextShape != nil && tetro.nextShape!.blocks[0].sprite == nil {
        scene.addPreviewShapeToScene(tetro.nextShape!) {
            self.nextShape()
        }
    } else {
        nextShape()
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate it if I can get some guidance on how to save the scoreLabel.text and put it on a seperate @IBOutlet called hiscoreLabel using NSUserDefaults to store the data.

Basically, I want to use NSUserDefaults and keep updating the highest hiscore with the highest previousely obtained score's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Write data:**

`let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
prefs.setDouble(1.0, forKey: "bar")`

// iOS 7 and below

`prefs.synchronize()`

**Read data:**

`let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
prefs.doubleForKey("bar")`

**Delete data:**

`let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
prefs.removeObjectForKey("bar")`

// iOS 7 and below

`prefs.synchronize()`